# Weighted Polar Area Diagram

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am working on a Polar Area Chart using chart.js.

Ive been trying to create the diagram as four quadrants, each of which has a different weight.

I haven't been able to change the tooltip options to vary based on the values. If there is any other js framework which helps me do this, it would be great as well.

Comment: Could you be more specific how you want to change the tooltip text in the the Chartjs polar chart? The label property on each item becomes the tooltip text.

Comment: Could you post you code and describe what you what the tooltip text to be,